# Can Microsoft Graph API access emails on stored on exchange server?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I am having 404 issues trying to get an inbox of a user through microsoft graph. I think I might recall reading somehwere that Graph API can only access emails stored on 365. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a preview capability that allows you to access mailboxes, calendars and contacts for on premise data if your exchange infrastructure has configured in an hybrid mode. This takes a few pre-requisites on the infrastructure side and you can learn more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support)